# How to give multiple buttons different outcome but same action with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, menu, coffeescript

Is it possible to make multiple buttons which will show different menu's but with the same jquery script, as shown as below?

So simply said, this effect but with multiple buttons each showing their own push-menu

Could this be possible with this code as shown below?

(I see this code snippet doesn't work because of coffeescript but it's the same as this https://codepen.io/danjuls/pen/lefcG )

```js
button = $('.mobile-menu')
container = $('.container')
body = $('body')

bodyClick = (event) ->
  if not $(event.target).closest('.menu').length
    body.off('click')
    container.toggleClass('menu-open')

button.on 'click', (event) ->
  event.stopPropagation()
  event.preventDefault()
  
  setTimeout (->
    container.toggleClass('menu-open')
    return
  ), 25

  body.on 'click', (event) ->
    if container.hasClass('menu-open')
      bodyClick(event)
```

```css
@import compass

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans)
  
*,
*:after,
*::before 
  box-sizing: border-box


html,
body,
.container,
.pusher,
.content
  height: 100%

body 
  background: #444
  color: fab
  font-weight: 300
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif

a 
  text-decoration: none
  color: #fff
  outline: none

ul
  list-style: none
  margin: 0
  padding: 0

button
  border: none
  padding: 0.5rem 1.2rem
  background: #388a5a
  color: #fff
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif
  font-size: 1rem
  text-transform: uppercase
  cursor: pointer
  display: inline-block
  margin: 1rem
  border-radius: .3rem


button:hover
  background: #2c774b
  
.content 
  overflow-y: scroll
  background: #f3efe0

.content,
.content-inner
  position: relative


.container 
  position: relative
  overflow: hidden

.pusher 
  position: relative
  left: 0
  z-index: 99
  height: 100%
  transition: transform 0.5s

.pusher::after 
  position: absolute
  top: 0
  right: 0
  width: 0
  height: 0
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2)
  content: ''
  opacity: 0
  transition: opacity 0.5s, width 0.1s 0.5s, height 0.1s 0.5s

.menu-open .pusher::after 
  width: 100%
  height: 100%
  opacity: 1
  transition: opacity 0.5s

.panel
  position: absolute
  top: 0
  left: 0
  z-index: 100
  visibility: hidden
  width: 300px
  height: 100%
  background: fab
  transition: all 0.5s


.panel::after
  position: absolute
  top: 0
  right: 0
  width: 100%
  height: 100%
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2)
  content: ''
  opacity: 1
  transition: opacity 0.5s


.menu-open .panel::after
  width: 0
  height: 0
  opacity: 0
  transition: opacity 0.5s, width 0.1s 0.5s, height 0.1s 0.5s
 

.menu-open .pusher 
  transform: translate3d(300px, 0, 0)

.panel
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)

.menu-open .panel 
  visibility: visible
  transition: transform 0.5s

.panel::after
  display: none
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="pusher">
    <div class="panel">
      <h2>Sidebar</h2>
      <nav class="menu">
        
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Data 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Data 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Data 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Data 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Data 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
     </div>
     <div class="content">
    <div class="content-inner">
        <h1>Testing a push menu</h1>
        <button class="mobile-menu">Push</button>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is too broad. Almost any menu toggle script does what you describe. Please edit to ask a more specific question.

Comment: @isherwood I'd like to make multiple buttons, which each shows it's own push menu. So this effect but then multiplied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is to link the buttons to different menu's e.g. by tagging the buttons with data-menu="menu-1" attributes and giving corresponding class to the menu inside the panel.

Then toggle the visibility of the menus inside the panel, by hiding all menus and showing the menu with the corresponding value of the button's data attribute.

I made a working fork of your demo and it is available at;
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OmJgbm

**JS:**

```
button = $('.mobile-menu')
container = $('.container')
body = $('body')

bodyClick = (event) ->
  if not $(event.target).closest('.menu').length
    body.off('click')
    container.toggleClass('menu-open')

button.on 'click', (event) ->
  event.stopPropagation()
  event.preventDefault()

  $('.js-menu').hide();
  menu = $(this).data('menu');
  $('.' + menu).show();

  setTimeout (->
    container.toggleClass('menu-open')
    return
  ), 25

  body.on 'click', (event) ->
    if container.hasClass('menu-open')
      bodyClick(event)
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="pusher">
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="js-menu menu-1" style="display:none;">
        <h2>Sidebar 1</h2>
        <nav class="menu">

          <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Data 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Data 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Data 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Data 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Data 5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="js-menu menu-2" style="display:none;">
        <h2>Sidebar 2</h2>
        <nav class="menu">

          <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Data 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Data 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Data 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Data 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Data 5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="content">
          <div class="content-inner">
        <h1>Testing a push menu</h1>
        <button class="mobile-menu" data-menu="menu-1">Open menu 1</button>
        <button class="mobile-menu" data-menu="menu-2">Open menu 2</button>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hopefully this was what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this is exactly what i was looking for.